# Is there a chart comparing airports in London and the south-east?

Tags: uk, airports, london

I am interested to know how London airports compare to each other, including if travelling to a different airport - such as Southend, Southampton or Bristol - might be more feasible.

Despite Gatwick (LGW) being further away than City (LCY) and Heathrow (LHR), it can often be much faster to get to this airport.

One thing to consider at Heathrow is not only the distance between terminals, but the frequency of transit connections between terminals. On one occassion, it took 45 mins to get from the Central Bus Station to the Terminal 5 departure hall, of which 15 mins were spent waiting for the connecting Piccadilly line (Heathrow Express had the same gap between services also).

Fares for Gatwick Express can cost as much as £35 and for Heathrow Express can cost as much as £41 for a standard ticket. By contrast, a one-night stay at a nearby Premier Inn or Travelodge can be around £29 or even less!

Information of interest would be:

- Journey times from London to the airport.
- Cost of that journey to the airport.
- Cost of a hotel near that airport.
- Transfer times between terminals (if more than one).
- Average times through bag drop, airport security and boarding.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the statement. London City Airport is a pretty nice pocket-sized airport which is very convenient for anyone in central or East London, with short check-in times, fast baggage delivery, and in most cases very little walking. The choice of flights is of course limited, but when the option exists, it's definitely my favorite.

Comment: London city center to the gate at Luton takes ~2 hours. I'm not sure any remote airport could beat that.

Comment: Gatwick is on the trainline south, so you're going to hardpressed to beat it, it's also very accessible from central London.  LCY and LHR too aren't actually that bad if taking hte tube.  LTN and STN though...(shudders)

Comment: That's a lot of informatin to want on a map. My hunch is that BHX is probably quicker to get to that Bristol, although it's a big airport so back to some of the downsides of the London airports. EMA is small and not too far away, but public transport links are soso. MAN is well linked but a bit far (and again bigish, so back to the same problems).
Hotel prices are so demand driven that there's no meaningful information that could be given.

Comment: London City (LCY) is going to be impossible to beat for destinations it serves. As for Heathrow, I haven't found it too bad as a departing passenger lately (transit is a different matter...), and arrivals has generally been fine too. I'd take Heathrow on a bad day over Luton on a good day every time, almost the same for Stansted, so it's starting to feel a lot like personal preference here

Comment: Your question implicitly asserts that everyone feels stressed at airports. You might - I certainly don't, nor do I find walking through some corridors at Heathrow a "logistical nightmare". There is the nucleus of a reasonable question here but you need to ask in a neutral way.

Comment: I've decided to compile my own data on this which I'll share soon; I've seen charts comparing airports around the world and I'm specifically talking about airports in proximity to London. Most of the time, airports are actually nice places to be.

Comment: Mostly depends where in London you're starting from and how close you are to different forms of transport.

Comment: @AdamElsodaney I never produced a chart, but http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62718/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-into-london-from-its-airports/62721#62721 might be of some use. Definitely would like to see a nice visualisation of it if you feel inspired :-)